# Find and extract date from string not working?

Tags: vba, excel

I am attempting to determine if the date that is inside of a string containing other text is less than the date in another cell, but for some reason, the function never seems to hit on the date formula, even when the date format matches my Like statement conditions.

Here is an example of what one of the cells looks like that I am attempting to extract from `1/9/2018 5:02AM Benjamin Button`

Please see the code below

```
Sub findAndCheck
 for i = 2 to lastrow ''Lastrow declared and set, just not shown here [i is global]
  if Getdate(cells(i,68).value2) then
    comments = "True"
  end if
 next i
End Sub


Public Function Getdate(expression As Variant) As Boolean
Dim dateconvert As Date  
  If (expression Like "*#/#/####*") Then
    dateconvert = CDate(Left(expression, 8))
      Getdate = CDate(expression) < CDate(Cells(i, 66))
  ElseIf (expression Like "*##/#/####*") Or (expression Like "*#/##/####*") Then
        dateconvert = CDate(Left(expression, 9))
        Getdate = CDate(expression) < CDate(Cells(i, 66))
  ElseIf (expression Like "*##/##/####*") Then
      dateconvert = CDate(Left(expression, 10))
      Getdate = CDate(expression) < CDate(Cells(i, 66))
  End If

End Function
```

Comment: This bit looks like an error to me: Cells(i, 66). What is it supposed to do?

Comment: Can you tell us what output you get?

Comment: @GregViers my mistake. That should be cells(i,68).value2. It's a value in a loop, I just cut that bit of code out to make it simpler to read. I've added it back in now.

Comment: @neophlegm literally none. It checks all 3 conditions in the functions and fails to meet any of them.

Comment: @Gurrito Ok that's what I thought. See my answer: It's not evaluating the date in `expression` because you're trying to extract the date from the whole text, instead of using what you already created in your `dateconvert` variable :)

Comment: `isdate(split("1/9/2018 5:02AM Benjamin Button", chr(32))(0))` should determine whether you have a leading date or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't include `i` as an argument for your function, so I did.

Also, just check if your `expression` contains a space, then perform a split on that.

```
Public Function Getdate(expression As Variant, i As Long) As Boolean

    Dim rawDate As Date
    If InStr(1, expression, " ") > 0 Then
        rawDate = CDate(Split(expression, " ")(0))
    End If

    Getdate = rawDate < CDate(Cells(i, 66))

End Function
```

You should also perform a check of `rawDate = 0`, which would mean that your string didn't contain a date at all.

Comment: The 'i' is handled in the above sub, which seems to work fine in other procedures? I'm getting an error on the last line for this one, though? It spits out Type Mismatch (error 13)

Comment: @Gurrito If you would use `Option Explicit` at the top of your module, you would realize that it's not "fine". `i` has a value of `0` (or more specifically `Null`) because you are not passing it to your function. It's fine that it's handled by your sub, but `i` is not a global variable so while it may be handled by your sub it has nothing to do with your function

Comment: @Gurrito above that line you are getting an error type: `Debug.Print rawDate` (new line) then `Debug.Print Cells(i, 66)`. You will be able to view this in your immediate window. Are they both dates?

Comment: @k.davis, i is a global variable in my project.

Comment: @k.davis the if statement isn't hitting.

Comment: @Gurrito your code didn't show that, so I just had to assume that you weren't declaring your variables at all. do a `Debug.Print expression` above the if statement and see if what it prints contains a space in it.

Comment: That's a fair point. Noted going forward. debug.print expression does contain a space:  1/22/2018 1:52 AM RL, Stein

Comment: @k.davis, this is going to sound insane. the debug.print expression printed out what i showed above (copypasted & changed name for privacy only), but now it's returning nothing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164370/discussion-between-k-ds-and-gurrito).

Comment: I had been making a stupid mistake(calling on cells in the wrong sheet). This solution is correct, though I did have to change the empty " "s to chr(32) as shown in Jeeped's solution in order to pick up the space. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`isdate(split("1/9/2018 5:02AM Benjamin Button", chr(32))(0))` should determine whether you have a leading date or not.

```
Public Function Getdate(expression As Variant, _
                        optional i as long = 2) As Boolean
    If isdate(split(expression, chr(32))(0)) Then
        Getdate = CDate(split(expression, chr(32))(0)) < CDate(Cells(i, 66))
    End If  
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem lies here:

```
Getdate = CDate(expression) < CDate(Cells(i, 66))
```

You won't be able to evaluate `CDate(expression)` as the full text of expression still contains something other than the date stamp. I imagine you want instead to check if your date conversion is less than the value in that cell:

```
Getdate = dateconvert < CDate(Cells(i, 66))
```

You also need to declare `i` somewhere. Presumably you want it as another argument in your function (for eg):

```
Public Function Getdate(expression As Variant, i as integer) As Boolean
```

Comment: Thanks for this neophlegm. The problem now is that it's not even getting down to this level. The if/elseifs are returning not true

Answer (score 1):

To extract a date from an expression similar to what you show (where the date is either at the beginning, end, or separated by a space from the rest of the string, you can use:

```
Option Explicit
Function GetDate(sExpression As String) As Date
    Dim v, w
v = Split(sExpression, " ")
For Each w In v
    If IsDate(w) Then
        GetDate = CDate(w)
        Exit Function
    End If
Next w

End Function
```

The function will return a zero if there is no date

And, to compare two cells, something like:

```
Sub findAndCheck
 for i = 2 to lastrow ''Lastrow declared and set, just not shown here [i is global]
  if Getdate(cells(i,68) > getdate(cells(i,66) and _
     getdate(cells(i,68) <> 0 and getdate(cells(i,66) <> 0 _
 then
    comments = "True"
  end if
 next i
End Sub
```